# RowSource Attibute of a ListBox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with the attribute 'RowSource' of my ListBox, and I don't understand why. Here my method:

```
Public Sub lbUsersInProgressRefresh()
'Variable declaration
Dim lastRow As Integer

'Refresh ListBox Users In Progress
lastRow = Worksheets("User In Progress").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Worksheets("Main").lbUsersInProgress
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnWidths = "50 pt;45 pt;45 pt;45 pt;45 pt"
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .RowSource = Sheets("User In Progress").Range(Sheets("User In Progress").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("User In Progress").Cells(lastRow, 5)).Address
End With

End Sub
```

Here my data:

[image: Data]

Here the result of my ListBox:

[image: ListBox]

I hope that the data come to the ListBox with good title. Have you got an idea to manage this please ?

Comment: You should use `ListFillRange` for an activex listbox on a worksheet, not `RowSource`.